# Is it possible to have more than one user_class in Spree? Separate from roles

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, spree

I have a rails project that's using both Spree and Refinery together. In order to have uniform authentication, the Spree.user_class has been set to Refinery's User class. I'm now looking to have *another* user_class through Spree for customers, one that won't have authentication into Refinery.

Is this even possible or would I be wasting time even looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering - the answer is no. The solution I'm going with is to just keep using Refinery's User class, assign roles and ensure that - in the case that a customer stumbles across /refinery - customers are just routed with Spree authentication.